# Explanation of transfer function from electrical design

Tags: transfer-function

I am a bio-engineer student so not that profound with electric cirquits. But I understand how transfer function works. My problem is the following: I have found a source from literature that derives a transfer function from a given electrical circuit. The electrical circuit is the one I've attached as an image. It is actually a biological circuit based on a model of the mechanics in the lungs.

[image: Electrical circuit relating Pressure to Flow]

Now the transfer function from the paper is given by:

[image: Transfer function of model]

It is possible that the above transfer function is incorrect (Rst does appear in the transfer function and not in the diagram, which is weird). 
User rioaxe pointed out that the transfer function above is actually the impedance of the circuit, that is Pressure (P) / Flow (F) = Vin / Iin,  which is very logical because the equation relating pressure to flow is:  P = Raw * F,  with Raw the airway resistance. Equivalent to Vin = R * Iin  in electrical circuits.

The problem that I face now is how to derive the transfer function Vin / Iin from what rioaxe has given as answer. I never worked with electrical circuits like that before (in series + parallel).

If someone can help me derive the TF this will be very kind.
And thanks for who already tried to help.
Cheers

Here is a second picture of the (viscoelastic) model:
[image: Same model]

Comment: Have you tried Laplace Transform before? If no read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/Laplace_Transform) you will get a glimpse of guidance. On the other hand, if you answered yes, please do edit your question and share with us the steps you have done. As this site encourages new users to chip in their effort first before help and guidance were given.

Comment: Seems like there is something missing in the diagram- There's no load on the right side, and there is reference to Raw and Rst which do not appear in the diagram. As it stands there's no current path in the circuit.

Comment: @JohnD I think R == Rst == Raw. And it is actually a biological circuit of the lungs that is based on an electric circuit,so I don't know how to account for the current path.

Comment: @Sarenya I know how the Laplace transform works, if I use it for example in a feedback system. But I have no idea how to use it in such an electronical system as in the picture. That is getting the differential equation from such a system.

Comment: I've added another picture that is exactly the same circuit as the first one. If you assume Vin (= Flow) as input from the left side and Vout (= Pressure) as output at the right side, could you derive the differential equation from the circuit? Cause I really don't know how to do that...

Comment: Looks im too rusty to derive the equation. Hope this link helps you out [Linear Viscoelasticity](http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/users/papers/engr/ernesto/mannan/MEF2/Linear%20Viscoelasticity.ppt)

Comment: Rafi-are you sure about the circuit and about the given function? Is the denominator correct? No "1" (as in the numerator)?

Comment: @LvW About the circuit I am sure. I find several sources from literature that show the same circuit. The given transfer function might be wrongly computed, I got it from only one research. Have you found another transfer function or you are just assuming there should be a "1" in the denominator from common knowledge? (I would also think there could be a "1" out there).

Comment: For the circuit shown, without extra components, Vin = Vout - this means your assumptions about flow and pressure equating to Vin and Vout are incorrect. You need to provide a better example.

Comment: Transfer to electrical equivalent quantities I would say: Flow is identical to current and pressure is identical to voltage. However, a voltage does exist only BETWEEN two nodes. If pressure=voltage, where are the two nodes? There is no voltage "coming out" of the circuit.

Comment: More than that, the given function contains elements (Three different resistors) which are NOT shown in then figure. Don`t you think that RST is in series to CST and RAW is a load resistor (not shown in the circuit). In accordance with my assumption (flow=current and pressure=voltage the given function has the unit V/I=R in ohms which is an indication for a (missing) load resistor (RAW?).

Comment: @LvW I am sure R in the first figure is actually Raw (see third figure also). So R == Raw. What I am not sure is whether R == Rst. So Rst could be just a mistake in the transfer function, or like you say a missing load resistor whish is not shown in the circuit. The schematic created by rioraxe probably represents the electrical circuit in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In the model, it is not Flow in on the left side and Pressure out on the right side. But rather:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyQcqI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$ Transfer\ Function = \frac{Pressure}{Flow} = \frac{Vin}{Iin} = impedance\ of\ the\ circuit $$

To analyze the circuit in Laplace s domain, substitute impedance of capacitor with 1/sC (impedance of resistor is simply R).

Comment: I think you are correct. This seems like a better representation of the circuit (instead of Vout/Vin). I still don't know how to put this form into a transfer function, though. Can you maybe help me out here? I am really curious to see how the transfer function looks like.

Comment: Yes - the given function is NOT the transfer function but the INPUT impedance of the shown circuit. But you have to incorporate the following modifications: (1) The circuit is to be grounded (as shown in the above picture), (2) R=RAW and (3) Denominator: Replace RST with RVE.

Comment: @LvW With the modifications u mentioned, do you then obtain the same input impedance of the circuit (i.e. the transfer function Pressure/Flow that is given from the paper)?

Comment: YES! I have learned how to use impedances and got exactly the same transfer function as in the paper (Rst in denominator should be Rve). So satisfied. Thanks to all!

Comment: Rafi: Note that the terms "flow" and "pressure" as shown on the first figure make no sense in connection with the interpretation of the given function (input impedance).

Comment: @LvW The third figure is a better representation of the situation, together with that of the answer. First figure like you said probably makes no sense. Flow should be Iin and Pressure Vin for the system.